# Combinatória matemática

Tags: algoritmo, combinações

Tenho uma lista de números ex:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

e preciso saber todas as combinações possíveis dessa lista lembrando que a lista pode conter n elementos, alguém tem algum exemplo de código ou poderia me ajudar?

Para esta lista de exemplo o resultado esperado seria:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]
[1,4]
...
[1,2,3]
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]
... e assim por diante.
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tens alguma coisa feita? Alguma ideia??

Comment: é interessante nos mostrar alguma tentativa para podermos ajudar

Comment: Em que linguagem de programação?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, acredito que um algorítimo genérico ajudaria, não achas?

Comment: Se a ordem não for relevante ([1,2] = [2,1]), podias considerar a tabela combinatória de 4 bit's. Terias 16 casos possíveis.

Comment: @Cold com certeza, é que achei que você estivesse tendo esse problema em uma linguagem de programação específica.

Comment: @Cold Se a ordem não importa, é combinação. Se importa, é permutação.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, exatamente isso, se for permutação a quantidade de resultados possíveis incrementa muito, e torna mais interessante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que você não especificou linguagem, vou dar um exemplo em Javascript:

```
var result = {};
function MeDaUmNumero(arr) {
    result[arr.join(", ")] = true;
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr[0];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var arrCopy = arr.slice(); // Isso copia o vetor em uma nova variável.
        arrCopy.splice(i, 1); // Isso remove o elemento no índice 'i'.
        MeDaUmNumero(arrCopy);
    }
}
```

Você chama a função passando seu vetor. No final, a variável `result` ser um dicionário onde as chaves são as combinações (os valores são todos, arbitrariamente, `true` - você pode usar outro valor). Vou deixar o esforço de análise do código pra você.

P.S.: esse algoritmo entrega as combinações não ordenadas. Para combinações ordenadas, basta reorganizar o vetor `n!` (fatorial de `n`) vezes, e para cada iteração chamar a mesma função de novo.

**Atualizando:** fiz uma versão iterativa ao invés de recursiva, [pra outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34652/1658). Segue aqui:

```
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var resultado = {
    "1": {}
};
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    resultado["1"][ar[i] + ""] = [ar[i]];
}

var tamanhoMaximo = ar.length;

for (var tamanho = 2; tamanho <= tamanhoMaximo; tamanho++) {
    var tamanhoAtual = resultado[tamanho + ""] = {};
    var tamanhoAnterior = resultado[(tamanho - 1) + ""];
    for (var chave in tamanhoAnterior) {
        var tempAr = tamanhoAnterior[chave];
        for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (tempAr.indexOf(ar[i]) == -1) {
                var novoAr = tempAr.slice();
                novoAr.push(ar[i]);
                novoAr.sort();
                tamanhoAtual[novoAr.join(",")] = novoAr;
            }
        }
    }
}
resultado;
```

Comment: Estou fazendo em php, vou traduzir para php aqui e testar este exemplo, muito obrigado, depois dou um retorno.

Answer (score 3):

Vou usar o PHP como base por causa da [pergunta relacionada sobre soma de números](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34656/70).

Se a ordenação da saída não tiver muito problema, este aqui é um [algoritmo bem eficiente](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kathleen/2013/12/31/algorithm-find-all-unique-combinations-in-a-list/):

```php
<?php
   $len = 10;
   for( $i = 1; $i < pow( 2, $len ); $i++ ) {
      for( $j = 0; $j < $len; $j++ ) {
         if( ( 1 << $j ) & $i ) echo $j + 1 . ' ';
      }
      echo "<br>\n";
   }
?>
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9JMZN6)**.

Se precisar ordenar a saída, veja uma "artimanha" usando *arrays*:.

```php
<?php
   $len = 10;
   $output = array();
   for( $i = 1; $i < pow( 2, $len ); $i++ ) {
      $line = array();
      for( $j = 0; $j < $len; $j++ ) {
         if( ( 1 << $j ) & $i ) $line[] = $j + 1;
      }
      $output[count($line)][] = $line;
   }

   foreach( $output as $group ) {
      foreach( $group as $line ) {
         foreach( $line as $item ) echo "$item ";
         echo "<br>\n";
      }
   }
?>
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/iaguiz)**.

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado os que contribuíram, com base no algoritmo do Renan converti em php e consegui encontrar o que eu esperava, muito obrigado.

```
$result = array();
MeDaUmNumero(array(1, 2, 3, 4), $result);
function MeDaUmNumero($arr, &$result) {
    if (!in_array(implode(',', $arr), $result)) {
        $result[] =  implode(',', $arr);
    }
    if (count($arr) === 1) {
        return $arr[0];
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $arrCopy = array_slice($arr, 0); // Isso copia o vetor em uma nova variável.
        array_splice($arrCopy, $i, 1); // Isso remove o elemento no índice 'i'.
        MeDaUmNumero($arrCopy, $result);
    }
}
```