# Encontrar somatória de valores em array

Tags: php, array

Preciso desenvolver um algoritmo que encontre um valor específico da somatória de alguns elementos de um array. Ex: tenho um array com **50** valores distintos e tenho um dado valor **"X"**.

Sei que a soma da combinação de alguns elementos deste array resulta neste valor, o que preciso é saber quais são os elementos dentro desta lista que dá esta soma. Não posso usar algoritmos de combinação pois acima de 9 elementos já dá limite de memória excedido e tenho *arrays* bem maiores que isso para calcular.

O código que tenho até agora é este:

```
/**
 * Class Teste
 */
class Teste
{
    static $values  = array(15.92, 53.27, 244.28, 388.46, 3.14, 2.92, 18.22, 4.03);
    static $include = array();
//    static         $expected = 712.02;
    static         $expected = 297.55;
    static         $ok       = false;
    private static $_instance;

    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public static function instance()
    {
        return static::$_instance = static::$_instance ?: new static();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        while (!static::$ok) {
            reset(static::$include);
            static::removeItem(key(static::$include));
            static::calc();
        }
        var_export(static::sum());
    }

    public static function calc()
    {
        foreach (static::$values as $k => $v) {
            var_export(static::$include);
            if (round(static::$expected, 2) == round(static::sum(), 2)) {
                static::$ok = true;
                break;
            } else if (static::$expected > static::sum()) {
                static::addItem($k);
            }
            if (round(static::$expected, 2) < round(static::sum(), 2)) {
                static::removeItem($k);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function addItem($k)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($k, static::$include)) {
            static::$include[$k] = round(static::$values[$k], 2);
        }
    }

    public static function removeItem($k)
    {
        unset(static::$include[$k]);
    }

    public static function sum()
    {
        return round(array_sum(static::$include), 2);
    }
}

Teste::instance();
```

Comment: O problema é legal, mas em php é realmente um desafio. Em JavaScript, eu criaria um ciclo setInterval para executar um algoritmo de forma controlada, sem estourar memória. Em php, acho que você terá que ver a criação de threads http://au2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pthreads.php ou alguma forma assíncrona de trabalhar, senão qualquer algoritmo vai estourar.

Comment: @user6492 usa uma solução iterativa que aí o máximo de memória que você vai consumir é mais ou menos do mesmo tamanho que a resposta final. O que consome mais memória num problema desses normalmente é a recursão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solução foi a mais eficaz para arrays com bastantes elementos.

```
$notas = [
  999 => 8,
  456 => 4,
  789 => 5,
  123 => 2,
];

asort($notas);

function remove_maiores_que($total, $numeros) {
    return array_filter($numeros, function($n) use ($total) {
        return $n <= $total;
    });
}

function find_soma($total, $numeros) {
    if ($total <= 0) return array();

    // primeiro remove os numeros maiores que o total buscado
    $numeros = remove_maiores_que($total, $numeros);

    $sum = array_sum($numeros);

    // se a soma de todos elementos do array for inferior ao total, não adianta procurar
    if ($sum < $total) {
        return array();
    }

    // já achou o array
    if ($sum == $total) {
        return $numeros;
    }

    // remove o maior e procura soma do restante
    while( end($numeros) ) { // enquanto tiver numeros no array
        // remove o maior e sua respectiva chave
        $key = key($numeros);
        $n = array_pop($numeros);

        // verifica se o numero já é igual ao total
        if ($n == $total) {
            return array($key => $n);
        }

        // no array que sobrou, procura pela diferença do total e o número maior removido acima
        $sub_total = $total - $n;

        $soma = find_soma($sub_total, $numeros);

        // se a soma não for vazia, então encontrou a sub soma
        if ( ! empty($soma) ) {
            // adiciona o numero atual no final da soma e retorna
            $soma[$key] = $n;
            return $soma;
        }
    }

    // retorna array vazio indicando que não encontrou nenhuma soma
    return array();
}

find_soma(6, $notas);
```

Answer (score 5):

### Solução otimizada:

Eu havia postado uma solução razoável (pode ser vista no histórico de edições da resposta), mas acabei pesquisando um pouco mais sobre esse tipo de combinação, e cheguei a esse código:

```
<?php
   static $values  = array( 15.92, 53.27, 244.28, 388.46, 3.14, 2.92, 18.22, 4.03 );
   static $expected = 297.55;
   static $precision = 100; /* para não ter problemas com ponto flutuante */

   $target = floor( $expected * $precision );
   $len = count( $values );
   for( $i = 1; $i < pow( 2, $len ); $i++ ) {
      $soma = 0;
      $set = array();
      for( $j = 0; $j < $len; $j++ ) {
         if( 1 << $j & $i ) {
            $set[] = $j;
            $soma += floor( $values[$j] * $precision );
         }
      }
      if( $soma == $target ) {
         // Estamos exibindo na tela apenas como demonstração. Se preferir pode armazenar.
         foreach( $set as $pos ) echo "[$pos]{$values[$pos]} ";
         echo " = $expected<br>\n";
      }
   }
?>
```

Graças à um [excelente algoritmo](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kathleen/2013/12/31/algorithm-find-all-unique-combinations-in-a-list/) otimizado para combinações únicas que encontrei, foi possível deixar o código bem mais rápido e com pouco uso de memória.

As soluções que eu tentei anteriormente estouravam o timeout de 5 segundos no IDEONE, mesmo com somente oito valores no array. Esta aqui está funcionando extremamente bem neste tempo com essa quantidade de dados.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Y6XM15)**.

Comment: Serve também pra encontrar todas as combinações como o anterior (apesar de enviar diretamente pra saída)?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Ele não repete resultados fora de ordem como o anterior. Como o objetivo proposto é encontrar quais dão a soma desejada, não faz muito sentido encontrar o mesmo resultado em ordens diferentes (vide nota no histórico de edições, versão 3 e seguintes). A busca por melhoria no algoritmo foi sobretudo para sanar estes casos.

Comment: Isso eu entendi, foi mais por curiosidade mesmo porque um tempo atr[as participei de um ~desafio~ para encontrar as combina;'oes dentre todos os n[umeros de uma dada matriz (independente da quantidade), mas todas as implementa;'oes eram muito lentas com PHP. Queria saber se essa sua [e melhor.

Comment: @Bruno eu editei a resposta por essa ter uma performance maior do que os outros caminhos que eu tentei, pela questãp matemática mesmo. Tecnicamente ela não é tão mais "rápida" no sentido de velocidade de processamento, mas o "pulo do gato" desta é que a busca por máscara binária elimina muitos sets que seriam gerados simplesmente para serem descartados em outras implementações, e daí que vem o verdadeiro ganho de tempo. Sugiro uma lida no [link do algoritmo original](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kathleen/2013/12/31/algorithm-find-all-unique-combinations-in-a-list/), tem uma explicação legal lá.

Answer (score 4):

Eu nunca programei em PHP na vida. Vou deixar um algoritmo aqui em javascript - peço que alguém crie uma nova resposta convertendo pra PHP (terá meu upvote).

Primeiro você pega todas as combinações possíveis (desconsiderando ordem). Já tinha feito algo parecido antes [em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34513/1658), mas fiz sem recursão aqui pra não estourar sua pilha ;)

```
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var resultado = {
    "1": {}
};
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    resultado["1"][ar[i] + ""] = [ar[i]];
}

var tamanhoMaximo = ar.length;

for (var tamanho = 2; tamanho <= tamanhoMaximo; tamanho++) {
    var tamanhoAtual = resultado[tamanho + ""] = {};
    var tamanhoAnterior = resultado[(tamanho - 1) + ""];
    for (var chave in tamanhoAnterior) {
        var tempAr = tamanhoAnterior[chave];
        for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (tempAr.indexOf(ar[i]) == -1) {
                var novoAr = tempAr.slice();
                novoAr.push(ar[i]);
                novoAr.sort();
                tamanhoAtual[novoAr.join(",")] = novoAr;
            }
        }
    }
}
resultado;
```

Agora é só percorrer o mapa e ver quais combinações dão sua soma.

```
function encontraCombinacoes (mapa, procurado) {
    for (var chave in mapa) {
        for (var subchave in mapa[chave]) {
            var array = mapa[chave][subchave];
            var soma = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                soma += array[i];
            }
            if (soma == procurado) {
                console.log(subchave);
            }
        }
    }
}
encontraCombinacoes(resultado, 6); // Só de exemplo
```

Note que você já podia verificar as somas no primeiro código. O que fiz aqui acumula combinações que podem passar do valor que você procura. Você pode deixar o algoritmo mais eficiente já contando as somas enquanto monta as combinações.

Quando alguém converter isso aqui pra PHP, posso apagar esta resposta.

**edit:** <strike>tem um erro no algoritmo e ele não pega todas as combinações (ficam faltando uns 20% delas). Assim que puder eu ajeito - ou alguém pode encontrar o erro e corrigir antes!.</strike> Corrigi!

Comment: Obrigado, vou converter e depois posto aqui.

Comment: Ainda tem erros nesse código! Eu vou ajeitar mais tarde!

Comment: Vai funcionar com 50 itens? Fizeste o que eu tinha em mente, mas ao invés de for, eu usaria um do … while com um contador externo e execução via setInterval, para garantir que não trave o navegador.

Comment: Vai funcionar com 50 itens sim, mas pode ficar lento pra caramba.

Comment: Porque usa esse var novoAr = tempAr.slice();

Comment: @Daniel Em javascript, a função `slice` faz uma cópia do array. Eu uso uma cópia pra deixar os arrays já montados intactos.